# Function eventually contractive implies it has unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space, and let $f:X\to X$ be eventually contractive (there exists $p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g:=f^{\circ p}$ is contractive). Then $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Is there a way to prove this without using the Banach contraction theorem? Would appreciate a hint.

Comment: You have to explain what "eventually contracttive" means here

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: So you know how to prove it using Banach f p theorem, and want a different proof?

Comment: Using the Banach theorem is actually just applying it. So I think this problem likely asks for more.

Comment: I don't think it is immediate. The contraction mapping theorem would imply that there is a unique fixed point for the power $f^{\circ p}$ only, not for $f$ itself.

Comment: You're right. What I should have been more attentive to is that it was to be proved that $f$ has a fixed point, not $f^p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose $f$ is continuous...

If $f^p$ is a contraction, then $(f^{np}(x))_n$ converges to the fixed point $x_0$ of $f^p$ for every $x\in X$. But then $f^{np+1}(x)$ converges to $f(x_0)$. But it also has to converge to $x_0$ (take $x'= f(x)$ as initial point). We conclude that $f(x_0) = x_0$.

Note that the fixed point will be the limit of $f^n(x)$ for every initial point $x$. The convergence rate is of the order $q^{\frac{n}{p}}$.